# Camel amqp uri with exchange and routingkey

Tags: apache-camel, amqp

I'm trying to use build a amqp uri with camel, follow the
[camel official document for amqp](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/amqp-component.html):

On the documents I found the uri for amqp ls like `amqp:destinationType:destinationName`.

I don't find any parameter for exchange and routingKey. How could I add these parameters to amqp uri?
I have tried `amqp:destinationType:destinationName?exchangeName=aaa&routingKey&routingKey=bbb`, but not works.

Thanks if any help!

Comment: Are you using [RabbitMQ](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/rabbitmq-component.html)? Can't find anything about routingKey on amqp component but there's such parameter for RabbitMQ.